# Eclipse Android SDK Manager window with no close button

Tags: android, eclipse

On my ubuntu 12.04 LTS workstation , I am using eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 to develop android applications.

When I update android SDK with the menu "Window / Android SDK Manager", a new window appears with the list of available packages.

The problem is that this window doesn't have any button to close it.
So I am obliged to kill the eclipse process or reboot the workstation to go out of this situation.

Am I alone with this problem ?

[image]

Comment: If I recall properly you need to resize the window or use TAB to switch to the button. I had that problem in the past.

Comment: Have you tried pressing escape button ?

Comment: I'm using the same setup. Escape works for me. And I also have the little x in the corner to close it. So I'm not sure what's going on with yours. Maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: ESC works perfectly. Thank you. I have no "x" to close the window.

Comment: I have the same problem with all dialog windows on Juno, and I can't move or resize the windows - very annoying... did your find a better solution then using the escape key to close... ?

Comment: No, I didn't find another solution. ESC is mandatory for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have also same problems on fedora 18 running eclipse juno and using lastest android tools 21.1, but the problems solve by pressing escape button